# Terms aggregations - Getting a total of each word across all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently I am performing a terms aggregation like so:

```
"aggs": {
    "wordcloud": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "transcription.raw",
        "size": 40,
        }
    }
}
```

I get back results like look like this (for example):

```
"aggregations": {
      "wordAppearences": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "banana",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "apples",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
    }
}
```

This query is counting the number of documents in which each word appears but it does not count how many times that word occurs within that field.  I want to get a count of how many times, across all documents, every word within the `transcription.raw` field occurs, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, it's not possible at the moment.